# Searching library consisting of links

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, links

We have a Sharepoint library which consists of links to source documents residing in other libraries within the same site collection. Is there a technical solution when performing a search, this search follows those links to the source documents and search into the content of said source document? We currently have Sharepoint on premises but will probably migrate to Sharepoint online.

Answer (score 0):

By design, the links of files cannot be used as **Query Keywords** to Search items.

So, users can't get results by searching links in SharePoint.

[image]